# Elasticsearch jdbc sort by _id

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I want to make my results sortable by _id so I need to add

```
"_id" : {
    "index" : "not_analyzed",
    "store" : true
}
```

to my index, correct?
here is my script for jdbc feeder:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Verzeichnis von JDBC -> wichtig, anpassen!
export JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME=~/Downloads/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0

bin=$JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME/bin
lib=$JDBC_IMPORTER_HOME/lib
echo '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxx",
        "user" : "xxxx",
        "password" : "xxxxxxx",
        "index" : "xxxxxxxx",
        "type" : "xxxxxx",
        "sql" : "SELECT xxxxxxxxx"
    }
}' | java \
       -cp "${lib}/*" \
       -Dlog4j.configurationFile=${bin}/log4j2.xml \
       org.xbib.tools.Runner \
       org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```

I added

```
"index_settings" : {
        "_id" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
        }
    }
```

after

```
"password" : "xxxxxxx",
"index" : "xxxxxxxx",
```

but it doesn't work
where do I add this setting?

Comment: `index_settings` is for number of shards, number of replicas etc. The `_id` config should go in the mapping itself. Take a look at this example: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#geo-shapes

Comment: I tried "type_mapping" : { "properties" : {
            "xxxxxx" : {
                    "_id" : {
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                 }
             }}
        } and getting the same error

Comment: `"_id" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
        }`, not `id`, but `_id`.

Comment: "type" : "xxxx",
        "type_mapping" : {
            "xxxx" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "_id" : { "index" : "not_analyzed", "store" : true }
                }
            }
        }
        "sql" :

Comment: Try `"type" : "xxxx", "type_mapping" : { "xxxx" : { "_id" : { "index" : "not_analyzed", "store" : true }, "properties" : {  } } } "`

Comment: same error: Failed to load settings from [args]
 at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:985)
 at org.xbib.tools.Importer.reader(Importer.java:111)
 at org.xbib.tools.Importer.reader(Importer.java:57)
 at org.xbib.tools.Runner.main(Runner.java:28)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries

Comment: Then I don't know. And I can't test this myself and try out different things.